# angular 2 reusability in ionic 2 with template overriding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have some angular 2 components that work fine for a web app.

So, I would want to reuse some of them in an ionic 2 application but without rewriting things.

Ionic has special directives, example: lists. I would have liked to be able to reuse my components by "adding" the ionic directives on top of it.

**Ionic syntax:**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let product of products">
        {{product.name}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**Example of angular components:**

*Main ionic page:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <ion-header>
        <ion-navbar>
            <button menuToggle>
                <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon> 
            </button>
            <ion-title>Products</ion-title>
        </ion-navbar>
    </ion-header>    
    <ion-content padding>
        <product-list [products]="products"></product-list>
    </ion-content>
  `,
  directives: [ProductListComponent],
  providers: [ProductService]
})
export class ProductsPage implements OnInit{

  products;

  constructor(
      private navCtrl: NavController, 
      private productService:ProductService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.all().subscribe(data => {
      this.products = data;
    });
  }
}
```

*A list of products:*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'product-list',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let product of products">
        <product-list-element [product]="product"></product-list-element>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  directives: [ProductListElementComponent]
})
export class ProductListComponent {

  @Input() products;

}
```

*An element of the list*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'product-list-element',
  template: `
    <div>
        <h3>{{product.name}}</h3>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ProductListElementComponent {

  @Input() product;

}
```

**Here in the example, there is no much logic so rewriting the template is ok but in the real case...**

I don't know how to handle this, I'm new in angular 2.

I think the beginning of an answer will be to hide less things and expose more peace of the template but maybe someone already done this before.

Maybe like so:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let product of products">
        <ion-icon name="leaf" item-left></ion-icon>
        <product-list-element [product]="product">
            <product-title [title]="product.title"></product-title>
        </product-list-element>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I've edited my question. I think I need to refactor my components and break them into smaller pieces that can be wired together in an ionic page.

Comment: What was your final solution to this?